# Como relacionar lista com sublistas em Python?

Tags: python, loop

Estou tentando fazer um laço de repetição pra percorrer as três listas, mas a lista de estoque tem uma lista com sublistas (estoque de cada loja). Como faço isso?

```
lojas = ['loja1', 'loja2', 'loja3', 'loja4']

estoque = [123, 49, 301, 21, 68, 79, 220, 135, 157, 277, 301, 155, 141, 134],[83, 120, 58, 303, 53, 69, 78, 221, 134, 156, 287, 306, 145, 143],[120, 18, 303, 43, 69, 78, 221, 134, 156, 287, 306, 145, 143, 311],[120, 88, 303, 53, 69, 78, 221, 134, 156, 287, 306, 145, 143, 303]

rotulos = ['Casillero del Diablo', 'Toro Loco', 'Cantina da Serra', 'Sangue de Boi', 'Chapinha', 'Bordeaux', 'Salton', 'Aurora Boreal', 'Country Wine', 'Wine10', 'Wine11', 'Wine12', 'Wine13', 'Wine14']
```

A lógica de resultado seria essa:

```
print(lojas[0], rotulos[0], estoque[0][0])
print(lojas[0], rotulos[1], estoque[0][1])
print(lojas[0], rotulos[2], estoque[0][2])
# ...
```

Answer (score -3):

Olá você pode utilizar o laço de repetição "foreach".

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Você pode simplicar utilizando while, mais um contador.

Ou caso queira algo mais fácil, pode utilizar pandas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/

Recomendaria um curso rápido sobre o básico da linguagem em: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud1110 - Tem legenda em português.